# How to run C++ code inside terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am unable to input values in output tab and wanted to run code directly inside the terminal.In previous version I was able to do so with the changes in settings.json file which is mentioned below but in the latest version 1.38 I was unable, Help.

```
[
 {
 "color-highlight.markerType": "dot-before",
 "editor.formatOnSave": true
 "explorer.confirmDelete": false
},
{
 "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
]
```

Comment: If you know where the executable is created, then you should be able to actually create a terminal and run it there. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: You can bring up a terminal in vscode and compile/run your code from there. Do you mean you can't open a terminal right now?

Comment: I want to show up the output directly on terminal after i run it rather than going to the terminal and opening the file there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried using CodeLLDB?

https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md##stdio